# .htaccess RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

`.htaccess` code is,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^p/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ redirect.php?url=$1  [NC,L] #
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ product.php?seo_id=$1 [NC,L] #
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ catalog.php?seo_id=$1 [NC,L] #
```

I'm trying to access `http://example.com/directory/` which is already exist in server but i can't access it. There is no any error occuring but, if there is a request for already existant directory, rules after  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` should not be applied.

But in this case one of the 3 rules are applying.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is seems not working.

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? What URL are you trying to access ?

Comment: please review my edited answer.

Comment: And what's the error ? Is one of the 3 rewriteRule used ?

Comment: yes that are used. But if there is a request for already existant directory, rules after `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` should not be applied. am i right ?

Comment: There is not any error but one of the next 3 rules are applied which shouldn't be.

Comment: Only your first rule is linked to your condition. RewriteCond is applied to next rule only. So your directory is matched in your third rule

Comment: what i have to do if there is a directory request recieved then the contents of that directory should be served. And none of those next 3 rules shouldn't be applied.

Answer (score 2):

RewriteCond only applies to the next RewriteRule, not to all of them. You should then duplicate them like so :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ redirect.php?url=$1  [NC,L] #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ product.php?seo_id=$1 [NC,L] #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ catalog.php?seo_id=$1 [NC,L] #
```

An alternative solution consists in using the S flag (skip) and invert the RewriteCond : [Apache doc for S flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s) or [examples](http://blog.smarchal.com/plusieurs-rewriterule-pour-une-rewritecond) (article in French, but the htaccess snippet don't need translation :) )

---

EDIT with another solution (not tested) :

```
# if it's a file or a folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [S=3] # then skip the next 3 rules
RewriteRule ^p/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ redirect.php?url=$1  [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ product.php?seo_id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ catalog.php?seo_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is there any solution if i want to write only once instead of writing everywhere before all rules ( brute force everywhere)